# How to link torch from anaconda to python file?

Tags: python, pytorch, conda, torch

I have got python38,37 and anaconda on my machine. I did install torch via conda:

```
    conda --version
    conda 4.8.4
```

However, my python file can't import torch, running `pip install torch` gives famous `no module nn.wrap` found error. I can import torch in jupyter(anaconda distro) though.

I tried fixing nn.wrap bug, but failed:

```
    pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu90/torch-1.1.0-cp38-cp38m-win_amd64.whl
```

Or

```
    pip install torch===1.6.0 torchvision===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Did not work.

I just want to use that torch from anaconda, how to import it instead of searching it in python3.8 dir?

Comment: verify that you're using the correct python. `which python` it should return the path to anaconda.

Comment: Also run a sanity check: If you installed with conda, then run `conda list` and see if the torch package shows up.